# I have yaml pipeline wh'll create my az resources(rg,vnet,aks..)using tf in 4 regions.With same piplin i want to create acr in 2 regions?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

I want to create acr in 2 regions & other 2 regions I want to skip? With same yaml pipeline, how can I achieve this?

Like this, I am creating acr

```
# ---- create new resource group account
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name =  var.resource_group_name 
  location            = var.location 
 
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                      = var.azurerm_container_name
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  location                  = var.location
  sku                       = var.sku
  admin_enabled             = var.admin_enabled
  georeplication_locations  = var.georeplication_locations
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to solve your issue with the `count` and `list` variables, or you can use `for_each` to solve it.

count and list:

```
variable "regions" {
  default = [
    "West US",
    "East US"
  ]
}

variable "acr_names" {
  default = [
    "acr_west",
    "acr_east"
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  count                     = 2
  name                      = element(var.acr_names, count.index)
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  location                  = element(var.regions, count.index)
  sku                       = var.sku
  admin_enabled             = var.admin_enabled
  georeplication_locations  = var.georeplication_locations
  
}
```

For_each:

```
variable "acrs" {
  default = {
    acr_west = "West US",
    acr_east = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  for_each = var.acrs
  name                      = each.key
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  location                  = each.value
  sku                       = var.sku
  admin_enabled             = var.admin_enabled
  georeplication_locations  = var.georeplication_locations

}
```

Choose one you like to solve the issue.

Comment: But i am running the acr module with same yaml pipeline which have aks creating in all 4 regions with acr link and giving error for linking aks with acr on 2 regions where acr is skipped

Comment: @satishp Can you share the Terraform code and the error messages?